# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNPaypal.requestOneTimePayment')

Tags: react-native, expo

I have installed **react-native-paypal** in my React Native project built using **expo**. But while running project I am facing error like this. I have also run "react-native link" but the error remains there.

Here is my code:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import _ from "lodash";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  List,
  ListItem,
  Body,
  Left,
  Thumbnail,
  Header,
} from "native-base";
import appStyles from "../../theme/appStyles";
import { Colors, Layout } from "../../constants";
import styles from "./styles";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5";
import PayPal from "react-native-paypal";



class HomeFilterHeader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }  
  
  goToPaypal = async () => {
    await this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
    PayPal.paymentRequest({
      clientId:
        "AbyfNDFV53djg6w4yYgiug_JaDfBSUiYI7o6NM9HE1CQ_qk9XxbUX0nwcPXXQHaNAWYtDfphQtWB3q4R",
      environment: PayPalAndroid.SANDBOX,
      price: "42.00",
      currency: "USD",
      description: "PayPal Test",
    })
      .then((confirm, payment) => console.log("Paid"))
      .catch((error_code) => console.error("Failed to pay through PayPal"));
  }
  render() {
    const { user, userBalance } = this.props;
    return (
      <Header style={styles.header}>
        <View style={[appStyles.row, { paddingTop: Layout.fourthIndent }]}>
          <List>
            <ListItem
              avatar
              noBorder
              onPress={() => this.props.onOpenProfile()}
            >
              <Left>
                <Thumbnail
                  source={{ uri: user && user.user && user.user.image }}
                />
              </Left>
              <Body>
                <Text style={appStyles.textBlack}>
                  {user && user.user && user.user.user_name}
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    color: Colors.secondary,
                    fontSize: Layout.halfIndent,
                  }}
                >
                  {" "}
                  <Icon
                    name="coins"
                    size={Layout.halfIndent}
                    color={Colors.secondary}
                    style={{ paddingRight: 1 }}
                  />{" "}
                  {userBalance &&
                    userBalance.user_balance &&
                    userBalance.user_balance.point_balance}{" "}
                  / ${" "}
                  {userBalance &&
                    userBalance.user_balance &&
                    _.round(userBalance.user_balance.winning_amount, 2)}
                </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.addFundsButton}
                  onPress={() => this.goToPaypal()}
                >
                  <Text style={appStyles.textWhite}>Add Funds</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </Body>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </View>
      </Header>
    );
  }
}
// Exports
export default HomeFilterHeader;
```